# How to make different ability on diferent pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers Courses and Teachers, and I need to make diferent abilities from user.User must can manage Teachers and read Courses, but if I change `can :read , Course`, on `can :manage, Coorse` it changes abilities on Teachers page too.I use CanCanCan gem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an additional argument to the ability class based on your requirement and add conditions

```
def initialize(user, params: {})
  roles = user.roles

  can :manage, :report if params[:current_page] == 'teachers'
end
```

And you need to override current_ability method to pass additional params from the controller

## In controller

```
def current_ability
   @current_ability ||= Ability.new(@current_user, params: { current_page: 'teachers' })
end
```

Note: I just added conditions just to show how to use them. You need to change it based on your requirement

One more thing is pundit(https://github.com/varvet/pundit) will be a good choice for controller level permissions. You can try that if you just started with authorization